# How to catch exception with action composition in Play 2.3.X

Tags: composition, playframework-2.3

I'm developing an application using Play 2.3.1.
I'm annotating all my controllers with the following Action :

```
@Override
public Promise<Result> call(final Context ctx) throws Throwable {
    try {
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    } catch (MyCustomException e) {
        return handleCustomException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return handleUnexpectedError(e);
    }
}
```

The aim of this action is to catch any exception thrown by a controller method in order to send a clean message to the user.
`MyCustomException` is my application specific exception that extends `Exception`.

The problem is that even if I throw a `MyCustomException` in the method of my controller, the corresponding catch statement is never executed.
I always have a `RuntimeException` caused by my `MyCustomException`.

The consequence is that no matter what exception occured, the user always sees the result sent by `handleUnexpectedError(e)`.

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, the guilty is the `Security` action of Play.
More details here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/AY4NuQziYyM

Because I added my custom actions at `AbstractController` level and the `@Authenticated(Authenticator.class)` annotation at the controller level, the security action composition is the last one to be executed.

Because of the [Security.java](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Security.java) at line 51, even if my exception is expected, Play throws a `RuntimeException`.

So the solution is to add the security annotation at method level in order to be sure that it is executed before the first execution of the method.